# Bootstrap Date picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

Hey this question might have been asked before, however I haven't been able to  find a solution.

I have two bootstrap date pickers. Based on the first date selection the second date should be restricted to the first date + 15.

I would like the vice-versa to happen as well. When a user selects the second date first the first date should be restricted to the second date - 15.

My code so far :

```
    var nowTemp = new Date();
    var now = new Date(nowTemp.getFullYear(), nowTemp.getMonth(),   nowTemp.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);
    var checkin = $('#inputDate1').datepicker({
        onRender: function (date) {
            return date.valueOf() > now.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
        }
    }).on('changeDate', function (ev) {

        //made changes to condition below
        var newDate = new Date(ev.date)
        checkout.setValue(newDate);
        checkin.hide();
        $('#inputDate2')[0].focus();
    }).data('datepicker');
    var checkout = $('#inputDate2').datepicker({
        onRender: function (date) {
           //made changes to below line
           var after = new Date(checkin.date);
           after.setDate(after.getDate() + 14);
           if(now.valueOf() > after.valueOf())
               {
               return (date.valueOf() <= after.valueOf()) && (date.valueOf()>= checkin.date.valueOf()) ? '' : 'disabled';              
               }
           else if(after.valueOf() > now.valueOf())
               {
               return (date.valueOf() <= now.valueOf()) && (date.valueOf()>= checkin.date.valueOf()) ? '' : 'disabled';
               }
        }
    }).on('changeDate', function (ev) {
        checkout.hide();
    }).data('datepicker');
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: make a fiddle, we could help you on this...

Comment: just a note, i don't think onRender is the appropriate event. check the docs if you find something more usefull.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok i figured out how to do it and here i paste my working code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var nowTemp = new Date();
    var end = new Date();
    var start; 

  $('#start').datepicker({
      startDate: start,
      endDate: end,
      autoclose: true

  }).on('changeDate', function (e){
      var tempdate = new Date(e.date);
      var tempdate1 = new Date(e.date);
      tempdate1.setDate(tempdate1.getDate() + 15);
      $('#end').datepicker('setStartDate', tempdate);
      $('#end').datepicker('setEndDate', tempdate1);
  });

  $('#end').datepicker({
      startDate: start,
      endDate: end,
      autoclose: true
  }).on('changeDate', function (e){
      var tempdate = new Date(e.date);
      var tempdate1 = new Date(e.date);
      tempdate1.setDate(tempdate1.getDate() - 15);
      $('#start').datepicker('setStartDate', tempdate1);
      $('#start').datepicker('setEndDate', tempdate);
  });


});
```